# How to calculate a value from existing javascript source and display it in Jquery Data table

Tags: datatables

Is it possible to display an extra column under Jquery Datatables by name SubPrice which is calculated dynamically  based on existing  javascript source .

This is my javascript source

```
var json = [
  {
    "Name": "ONE",
    "Price": "12" ,
    "Total" : "120"
  },
  {
    "Name": "TWO",
    "Price": "100",
     "Total" : "500"
  },
  {
    "Name": "THREE",
    "Price": "42" ,
     "Total" : "300"
  }]

 $(function()
  {
    //$("#kiran").dataTable();
    //displayData();
 var table =   $('#kiran').dataTable(
    {
      "order": [
        [1, "desc"]
      ],
      "paging": false,
     "aaData": json,
      "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "Name" },
        { "mDataProp": "Price" }
    ]

    });

setInterval (function test() {
         table.fnDraw();
       }, 3000);

  })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cv04pp37/1/

I mean right now its showing two values  tables and now i want to display an extra column by name **Subprice** which is calucuated as `Total - Price`  and sow it this way

[image]

Comment: Please reduce the huge white area of the image :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can using mrender, here is a example:

```
"aoColumns": [
   //other columns
   //dynamic column needed
   { 
     mRender: function(data, type, row){
        return row[x] + row[y]; //here you can make the operation you want
     }
   }
 ]
```

ps: i didn't test but it should work